# Can a div be shown outside of browser window?

Tags: javascript, html

I've noticed that the HTML SELECT dropdown can be drawn outside of the browser window.
For example look at it:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select

Make your browser's window height very small, and you'll notice that even if it's small the html select dropdown goes beyond the edges of the browser's window.

Now I'm making my own dropdown using absolutely positioned divs with a high z-index, but they seem to be cut off by the browser window edges if the window is very small. Is there a way to do this or make it act like an html select?

Comment: selects are windowed elements, you are not going to make divs or any html element act like that.

Comment: No, you cannot do that.  `<input>` and `<select>` elements are drawn by the OS, not the browser (meaning they are native UI elements); they are special.

Comment: It's similar to the difference between an `alter()` or `confirm()` pop-up and drawing a dialog using a `DIV`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot draw divs outside the browser window.

The dropdown menu is different in the sense that it is often rendered as native UI component. Some browsers may choose to allow native components to span outside browser windows, but this is not the norm.

Answer (score 2):

No, a `div` wouldn't exhibit this behavior.

The reason this happens with a `select` (and potentially other things, like a text box or a button perhaps, depending on the browser and the host system) is that the host system uses extra-browser functionality to render that element.  The browser uses the system's API to actually draw and use that element (same with text boxes, buttons, etc).

A `div`, by itself, is rendered entirely by in-browser functionality and doesn't rely at all on the system API outside of the browser.